# Toggling display on button click works on first click but wont make display hidden again

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, display

I have a div I want to be hidden until a button is clicked, and when the button is clicked again their after, hide the div again. When I click it the first time to show the div it works, but the display wont hide again. I know the button works more than once because my console.log("hi") logs on every click.

```js
let menuBtn = document.querySelector("#menu-button");
let menuOption = document.querySelector(".menu-options");
menuOption.style.display = "none";

menuBtn.addEventListener('click',() => {
    console.log("hi");
    if (menuOption.style.display = "none") {
        menuOption.style.display = "initial"
    } else {
        menuOption.style.display = "none"
    }
});
```

```css
 #menu-button {

            margin: auto;
            background-color:transparent;
            outline: none;
            border: none;
        }
.menu-options {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: khaki;
            height: 100px;
            width: 30px;
        }
```

```html
 <button type="button" id="menu-button">
            hi
            <div class="menu-options">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        home
                    </li>
                    <li>
                       about
                    </li>
                    <li>
                       portfolio
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
          </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the value, but not assign. Therefore, you should use `===` instead of `=`

```
menuBtn.addEventListener('click',() => {
    console.log("hi");
    if (menuOption.style.display === "none") {  //this should use compare
        menuOption.style.display = "initial"
    } else {
        menuOption.style.display = "none"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best way of doing that is to use a class that hides your div.

And then using JS add or remove that class from elements to hide them or make them appear. You can implement that just using the syntax below.

```js
// Get the element from the DOM
const element = document.getElementById("<id of that element>");

// Add the class called `hide`
element.classList.add("hide"); 

// Remove the `hide` class
element.classList.remove("hide"); 

/* 
    Toggle the class `hide`. That means it will either remove 
    it if the element already has that class or add the that class
    it don't have that
*/

element.classList.toggle("hide");
```

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
const square = document.getElementById("square");


btn.addEventListener("click", ()=> square.classList.toggle("hide"));
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click me!</button>
<div class="hide" id="square"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

the correct way to  do that :

```js
const menuBtn = document.querySelector("#menu-button")
menuBtn.addEventListener('click',() => menuBtn.classList.toggle('noMenu'))
```

```css
#menu-button {
  margin           : auto;
  background-color : transparent;
  outline          : none;
  border           : none;
  }
#menu-button.noMenu  > div.menu-options { 
  display : none;
  }
.menu-options {
  position         : absolute;
  background-color : khaki;
  height           : 100px;
  width            : 30px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="menu-button" class="noMenu">
  hi
  <div class="menu-options">
    <ul>
      <li> home      </li>
      <li> about     </li>
      <li> portfolio </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```